# Install Spark in Eclipse IDE using Maven

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

I am trying to use Spark for my project.

```
import static spark.Spark.*;
//cannot be resolved
```

I am using Maven to build my project.
This is my pom.xml content.

```
<!-- Spark dependency -->
<dependency> 
     <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
     <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.1</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
<!-- End Spark dependency -->
```

Comment: Is `spark.Spark` supposed to be a class?

Comment: Even I had similar doubt, as I am using this reference I do not know how to go about the installation process.  http://sparkjava.com/documentation#getting-started

Comment: That "spark" is a completely different thing. It's a web framework. Please go to the documentation on the Apache Spark website at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have wrong dependencies added in your pom.xml file. Add the following as dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you can start working:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test");
        sparkConf.setMaster("local[*]");

        SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate();

        Dataset dataset =  sparkSession.read().json("some_json_input_file_path");

        dataset.printSchema();
    }
}
```